# Maze Game Programming

Tags: java, swing, compilation

This my code for the simple maze game. Its being compiled and class file of MazeGame.java and Board.java are being created but not of Player.java and Map.java. The code is being compiled error free but its not running. Please help me out.

```
//MazeGame.java
package mygame;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MazeGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MazeGame();
    }

    public MazeGame() {
        JFrame f= new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Maze Game");
        f.setSize(450,450);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new Board());
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}   



//Board.java
package mygame;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Timer timer;
    private Map m;
    private Player p;
    private boolean win=false;
    private String Message="";
    private Font font = new Font("Comic Sans",Font.BOLD,50);

    public Board() {
        m = new Map();
        p = new Player();

        addKeyListener(new Al());
        setFocusable(true);

        timer = new Timer(25,this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        if(!win)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<14; y++) {
               for(int x=0; x<14; x++) {
                  if(m.getMap(x,y).equals("f")) {
                g.drawImage(m.getFinish(),x*32,y*32,null);
                  }
                              if(m.getMap(x,y).equals("g")) {
                g.drawImage(m.getGrass(),x*32,y*32,null);
                  }
                  if(m.getMap(x,y).equals("w")) {
                g.drawImage(m.getWall(),x*32,y*32,null);
                  } 
               }
            }
            g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(),p.getTileX()*32,p.getTileY()*32,null);
        }

        if(win)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(Message,100,300);
        }
    }

    public class Al extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if((keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_W) || (keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
                if(!(m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()-1).equals("w"))) {
                    p.move(0,-1);
                }
            }
            if((keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_S) || (keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
                if(!(m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()+1).equals("w"))) {
                    p.move(0,1);
                }
            }
            if((keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_A) || (keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
                if(!(m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()-1).equals("w"))) {
                    p.move(-1,0);
                }
            }
            if((keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_D) || (keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
                if(!(m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()-1).equals("w"))) {
                    p.move(1,0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(m.getMap(p.getTileX(),p.getTileY()).equals("f")) {
            Message = "WINNER!!!";
            win = true;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}       



//Map.java
package mygame;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Map {
    private Scanner s;
    private String Map[] = new String[14];
    private Image grass,wall,finish;

    public Map() {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("G://sonali_java//mygame//grass.png");
        grass = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("G://sonali_java//mygame//wall.png");
        wall = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("G://sonali_java//mygame//finish.png");
        finish = img.getImage();

        openFile();
        readFile();
        closeFile();
    }

    public String getMap(int x,int y) {
        String index = Map[y].substring(x,x+1);
        return index;
    }

    public Image getGrass() {
        return grass;
    }
    public Image getWall() {
        return wall;
    }
    public Image getFinish() {
        return finish;
    }

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            s= new Scanner(new File("G://sonali_java//mygame//Map.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading File!!!!");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            for(int i=0; i<14; i++) {
                Map[i] = s.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        s.close();
    }
}



//Player.java
package mygame;

import java.awt.*;

public class Player {
    private int tileX,tileY;
    private Image player;

    public Player() {
        tileX=1;
        tileY=1;
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("G://sonali_java//mygane//object.png");
        player = img.getImage();
    }

    public Image getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public int getTileX() {
        return tileX;
    }

    public int getTileY() {
        return tileY;
    }

    public void move(int dx, int dy) {
        tileX += dx;
        tileY += dy;
    }
}
```

Comment: why is this tagged jquery javascript and c++?

Comment: You need to state the problem(s) you are facing. We cannot help you until and unless we know what issues you are facing and what are you exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, don't override `paint()` of swing components. Override `paintComponent()` instead.

Comment: How are you compiling the code?

Comment: @AndrewThompson in command prompt its saying Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : Map

Comment: I did not ask how you were running the code, or the run-time output.  I asked how you were *compiling* the code?  Are you compiling it from the command line?  Using an IDE?  Using black magic..?

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to be mad but you are defining different folder locations

in some places `"G://sonali_java//mygane//object.png"`, check "mygaNe"

in some places `"G://sonali_java//mygame//Map.txt"`, check "mygaMe"

Are you sure while loading it does not throw a `NullPointerException` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you can, place code like

```
 public void draw(Graphics g){
   g.drawImage(playerImg, getX(), getY(), null);
 }
```

in your player class, thus leaving the player class with drawing the player and simply calling the players draw method inside your Board paint method? This can also be done for drawing the map. Remember to call the draw methods in the paint method.
ALSO, THIS
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("G://sonali_java//**mygane**//object.png");
check your directory location

Comment: *"Are you aware that you can"*  That 3 lines of code 1) Should call the super method. 2) Is the wrong one for any `JComponent` 3) Has a wrong method call that would not compile.  --  New coders would be well advised to ignore the answer unless it is improved significantly.

Comment: can you expand on your reply Andrew, i am sure that i have used public void draw(Graphics g){..} before without any compilation errors

Comment: @AndrewThompson `Player` does not extend `JComponent`. (That `drawImage()` call still does not exist, though).

Comment: @kiheru  Oh, right you are!  Cancel points (1) & (2).  :P  For point (3) add an `ImageOberver` (or `null`) to the method call.

Comment: does this mean i am kinda right with the above method?, excluding the fact i didn't add null in here g.drawImage(playerImg, getX(), getY(), <should be here>); and if so, do i win a prize? lol